# No error shown when calling a method marked NS_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Say I have a base class with an init declared as NS_UNAVAILABLE:

```
@interface MyBase : NSObject
-(instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILEBLE;
@end
```

and a derived class (we'll call it MyDerived) that in its .m tries to implement that init (lets say accidentally since the method isn't actually available):

```
@implementation MyDerived
-(instancetype)init {
  self = [super init];
  if(self){
  }
  return self;
}
```

even though the init being called in the parent class is marked as NS_UNAVAILABLE still no warning or error will be thrown and the code compiles fine.

However, if we declare our init in our derived class .h:

```
@interface MyDerived : MyBase
-(instancetype)init;
@end
```

then a error will be shown!

Is this intended behavior, and if it is what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: `extends`? Did I miss something.

Comment: oops sorry, was just typing out pseudo-code at first and forgot to correct

Answer (score 1):

The `NS_UNAVAILABLE` macro is used when bridging to Swift.  Swift is much more strict when it comes to constructors, and method invocation in general, and it will not allow calling a method marked with this macro.  Objective-C, on the other hand, will let you call a method that doesn't even exist.

Additionally, the macro means that the method is unavailable to users of the class, not the class itself.  This is why calling `[super init]` works, but declaring it publicly does not.

Comment: This isn't true though, inside the init method (or I think any other method marked NS_UNAVAILABLE) you can also call methods marked NS_UNAVAILABLE in other objects without Xcode showing an error. Its as if the preprocessor just doesn't check for these sorts of errors in a method marked NS_UNAVAILABLE for some reason which is what I don't understand.

Comment: BTW: In Objective-C the developer (the developer's code) never calls a method. It sends messages. While this is unimportant in many cases, in the context described by your answer, it is very important. So Objective-C allows sending messages to instances, that does not (explicitly) implement a method for that message. This is by intention, i. e. it allows forwarding

Comment: @J2K, If you are in a method that's not available to Swift, it doesn't matter if you call other methods unavailable to Swift.

Lots of the Swift-compatibility additions to Objc-C have corner cases and weird behavior when used with Obj-C itself.  Generic containers, for example.